# pass values from model to controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller:**

```
function active_event() {
   $this->load->view('active_event');
   $a = $this->load->model('Usermodel');    
}
```

**Model:**

```
function active() {

     $query = $this->db->query(" SELECT * from event WHERE start > FORMAT(Now(),'MM-DD-YYYY') AND  end < FORMAT(Now(),'MM-DD-YYYY')");

     foreach($query->result_array() as $row){

        $image = $row['image'];
        $mobile = $row['mobile'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $country = $row['country'];
        $id  = $row['id'];
        $this->session->set_flashdata('id', $id); 
     }

     $data = array('name' =>  'name',
               'image' => 'image',
                'mobile' => 'mobile',
                'email' =>'email',
                'country' =>'country',
                 'id'=> 'id'
               );

      return $data;
 }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the function you created in the model and then pass it to the view in this way:

```
function active_event() {
    //Load model
    $this->load->model('Usermodel');    

    //Call model function and save it to $data['a']
    $data['a'] = $this->usermodel->active();

    //Pass the $data array to the view - in the view you will be able to use $a
    $this->load->view('active_event', $data);
}
```